# Setting location of programatically created shape

Tags: android

I create a shape in a fragment like so:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val layout = view.findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.firstFragment)

    val cube = Cube(view.context)
    layout?.addView(cube)
    cube.x = 0F
    cube.y = 0F
}
```

I excpected to see the cube to be at point (0,0) but it actually is at the center of the screen = x, y = 0

I guess it's related to the fact that the screen hasnt finished loading/inflating?

(if i put `x = 0F; y = 0F` in the onDraw fun of the cube it will move to (0,0) but I dont want to do it like that)

How can I solve this? is there a listerner, some callback I can use inside cube (extends view) that tells me all is loaded?

thank you!

Comment: as far as i know from flutter it is between -1 and 1 it means -1 is starting point and 1  is ending point it was in flutter like this can you try to do it with -1

Comment: can u explain a bit more? im not sure what is between -1 and 1?

Comment: i mean leftest side of screen's x axis is -1 and rightest side of it is 1 but i am assuming like flutter can you just try to write -1 instead of zero if it is starting point of screen then my theory is correct.

Comment: Ah ok, so no.. didnt work :)
I added to my question - "if i put x = 0F; y = 0F in the onDraw fun of the cube it will move to (0,0) but I dont want to do it like that"